# Can I force an Eloquent model created_at to use unix_timestamp() for DB server time to combat time drift

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

I like storing my timestamps as epoch values, so in my model I use:

`protected $dateFormat = 'U';`

and in my migrations I use:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('created_at');
$table->unsignedInteger('updated_at');
```

On a single server with both PHP and the DB on, this gets the result I want.

But, this uses the local clock and in a scaled install with multiple 'front end' app servers all connecting to a single 'back end' database server, if any of the front end server clocks begin to drift I'm going to see entries in the DB where the (auto incrementing) `id` shows one order of insertion but the `created_at` showing a different order. This is not what I want.

With MySQL as the DB I'm trying to find a way to have `created_at` use the MySQL `unix_timestamp()` function so that the clock on the database server is used.

Is this even possible?